# Send closure from Objective-C to JavaScript in iOS React-Native

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

Is it possible to construct a closure in objective-c and pass it to javascript where it can be invoked?  The specific problem I am trying to solve is adding support for changing shipping methods and contacts in Apple Pay as part of the tipsi-stripe react-native module (something it doesn't do yet).  This is basically what I have so far, but the callback in javascript gets 'null'.

```
- (void) paymentAuthorizationViewController:(PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *)controller 
         didSelectShippingMethod: (PKShippingMethod *) shippingMethod
         completion:(nonnull void (^)(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus, NSArray<PKPaymentSummaryItem *> * _Nonnull))completion {
   id callback = (void (^)(NSArray* summaryItems)) {
     completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatusSuccess, nil, summaryItems); 
   }
   [self sendEventWithName: "@ShippingMethodChanged" body:@{@"selectedMethod": @"someMethodDetails", @"callback": callback}];
}
```

In javascript, I have something like this:

```
import { NativeEventEmitter, NativeModules } from 'react-native'
const { TPSStripeManager } = NativeModules;
const stripeEventEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(TPSStripeManager);
componentWillMount() {
  this.stripeOnShippingMethodChanged = stripeEventEmitter.addListener(
    'ShippingMethodChanged',
    (method, callback) => {
      // async compute some value then
      let summaryItems = await computeItemsWithMethod(method);
      callback(summaryItems);
    }
  );
}
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.stripeOnShippingMethodChanged.remove();
}
```

I'm assuming I have to somehow wrap the Objective-C closure so javascript knows how to invoke it but I can't find anything.  Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do what I was attempting to do here, the react-native bindings only support simple types that can be encoded as a string.  The solution that I ended up with based on patterns I found elsewhere is to store the completion as a property on the object, trigger an event that can be seen in js-land and provide another exported method that can be called to trigger the completion.  Code is here:

https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-stripe/pull/244/files